# Is it possible to use computer name instead of IP when connecting to SSTP VPN

Tags: macos, dns, sstp

I am connecting to VPN via SSTP on Mac. Example of command:

```bash
sudo /usr/local/sbin/sstpc --cert-warn --tls-ext --user <user> --password <password> <server_address> usepeerdns require-mschap-v2 noauth noipdefault noccp refuse-eap refuse-pap refuse-mschap defaultroute --log-stderr --log-level 4
```

everything is working fine except I can't use computer names from destination network only IP addresses. Eg instead of `ssh user@beebox.local` I need to use `ssh user@192.168.1.111`. I thought `usepeerdns` option is just for that purpose but it is not working. Maybe server does not provide client with DNS addresses? How can I check this?

Comment: `.local` names aren't resolved via regular (server-based) DNS, but by a related-but-distinct protocol called mDNS or Multicast DNS. mDNS normally operates separately on each local network. I'm not familiar with sstp, but I can certainly understand it not being forwarded over connections (and I'm not even sure it's possible to forward it).